# How to get follower/following user info in getstream

Tags: getstream-io

How to get the users whom I am following in getstream or users who are following me.

Suppose few users are following me, how can I get to know who is following me.

Comment: http://getstream.io/docs/#reading-feed-followers

Comment: can we get total number of user following activity. current documentation say nothing regarding this

Comment: that's because it's not currently supported by APIs (yet)

Answer (score 0):

You can get follower by calling method `followers()` . `feed.followers()` to get all followers, to paginate result you can give `limit` and `index` like `feed.followers(0,10)` fetch first 10 followers

you can fetch users whom you are following using `feed.following()` and also in this case use index and limit like `feed.following(0,10)` fetch first 10 users you are following.

Comment: And to check if user is following some specific feed you can do like
#check if user_feed_1 is following user:42 and user:43
user_feed_1.following(0, 2, filter=['user:42', 'user:43']) .

Comment: I got "results": [
        {
            "feed_id": "timeline:d9fa73e8-9cd7-4ac1-aa4b-fe148971e1f0",
            "target_id": "user:admin",
            "created_at": "2019-03-05T13:49:13.52832166Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-03-05T13:49:13.52832166Z"
        }
    ]

Can get the user: admin details,  as in the feed API.??